# how to use wxString  AfterLast() method for a frontslash (/)

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxString say "C:/Program Files/myfile/abcd.txt" .
I need to extract only "abcd.txt" and store it in a wxString object.

I have tried using the AfterLast( ) method of wxString class. But it doesnt seem to return the correct result for me only for "/" .Please let me know how I can extract the same.

Thanks,
Darzen

Comment: You should post your code, with the result it produces. 'Doesn't seem to work' could be anything or nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxFilename ( http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxfilename.html ) is very convenient for picking apart file paths.